# How to debug the absence of hydration in a nextjs page?

Tags: next.js

### Background:

We are have noticed that in production and in some staging environments, that the onClick handlers on a SSR page are failing to be called.   By comparing working and non-working (`npm run start`) deployments we've determined that the non-working deployments are not calling the render() methods of the components on the page immediately after page reload, whereas the working deployments do.  We are assuming that means that hydration is not occurring.

- Development deployments (`npm run dev`) work flawlessly
- We are seeing no browser-side console messages.
- We are seeing no server side warnings
- The `npm build --debug` suggests only to upgrade to the new ChunkGraph API.  Otherwise no warnings.

We are now wondering...

### QQ:

Short of starting with a fresh create-next-app again and gradually evolving the app towards our current implementation until it breaks, what are the suggested ways of determining the root cause(s) of a problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, my hydration issues only showed up in production, and only on the server. Running `next build` and `next start` didn't show any errors. Since user3624334's answer didn't really help me, I figured I'd reply with how I ended up finding the culprit.

Since I deploy to Vercel, and use Vercel's review apps, I ended up creating a Pull Request where I remove half of the page that was having the hydration issues, and continued bisecting until I found out which component was causing the issues. It took me three tries to find the component.

Once I had the component it was quite easy to figure out what was causing the issues (for me the hydration issue was caused by a timestamp being rendered in different ways).

This also explains why user3624334's answer didn't work for me, since I opened the page straight after building, at which point the time was still the same as during `next build`!

Answer (score 1):

One challenge here is that it appears that when SSR page hydration fails in next.js, a warning message will not necessarily be generated.

I hope someone has a better suggestion than the following, but I will offer this human script that worked several times for me:

- `git checkout -b "hydration-problem-02"` to create a branch for this effort
- add a `console.log('render called')`  to the top of the render() method of pages/_app.js.  This should produce a message on each hydrate, making it easy to notice when the page does/does-not hydrate.

Then repeatedly:

- simplify a significant portion of the app.
- `npm run dev` to run in dev mode
- confirm that your change did not break the app in unexpected ways
- `rm .next/  node_modules/  package-lock.json`
- `npm install && npm run build && npm run start`
- confirm that the above command completed successfully
- refresh the page in the browser
- check for the message in the *browser* console.
- `git commit -am "msg that indicates what you changed and if it helped"`
- if the problem remains, repeat these steps

Doing the commits above should help make the process more fool-proof.   Ex. If you think you might have forgotten to test in production mode, you can go back to that commit and retest to confirm you did not mis-test.

Once you have a working and non-working commit of the app, you can do a binary search for the error, either adding or removing smaller and smaller pieces of function.

The root causes of quiet hydration failures I've seen include:

- two modules that mutually import each other
- an `import '..../bootstrap.js'` in a component rather than _app.js